# How to set data validation to google form via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm creating google form with GAS

```
var form = FormApp.create("Test Form");
var item = form.addTextItem();
item.setTitle("Enter your email");
```

How can I set data validation setting for **item** programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation

```
// Add a text item to a form and require it to be a number within a range.
var textItem = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Pick a number between 1 and 100?');
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText(“Input was not a number between 1 and 100.”)
  .requireNumberBetween(1, 100)
  .build();
textItem.setValidation(textValidation);
```

Note: According to the Google Apps Script [release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/), on November 23, 2016 the forms validation classes for check boxes, generic data, grid items, paragraph text items, and text items were added.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible (yet).

You should *star* [issue 4216](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4216) to keep track of updates regarding this feature and kind of vote for it.

Comment: According to [#30](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761449#comment30) it's now available.